# Verify that $\alpha(a)\neq2$ for all $a$ where $\alpha(x): (2x + 1)/(x + 2)$

Tags: functions, discrete-mathematics

> If $A=  \mathbb{R} \setminus \{-2\}$ and $B = \mathbb{R} \setminus \{2\}$, let $\alpha: A \to B$ by $\alpha(x): (2x + 1)/(x + 2)$. Verify that $\alpha(a)\neq2$ for all $a \in A$.

As a hint, I was told to use contradiction.
If I use contradiction though, I feel as if I didn't do anything. If I say $\alpha(a) = 2$, it's clear that it's a contradiction since $2 \notin B$. Is that it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**By contradiction:** Suppose $\alpha(a)=2$. Then
$$
2=\frac{2x+1}{x+2}\Longleftrightarrow 2x+4=2x+1\Longleftrightarrow 4=1,
$$
which is clearly absurd. Hence, $\forall a\in A, \alpha(a)\neq 2$. $\blacksquare$

Comment: it does but wouldn't the fact that  2 is in B be a contradiction on itself. we say alpha: A -> to B where B is the reals except 2. I originally did that but I wasn't sure if we even need it to do that

Comment: @curiousmind1995 Yes, that's correct. If you are *given* that $B=\mathbb{R}-2$, then $2$ is not in the codomain for the mapping $\alpha\colon A\to B$. Since $\alpha$ is a mapping that sends an element from $A$ to $B$, and $2\not\in B$, then $\alpha(a)=2$ is *never* possible since you are given that $B=\mathbb{R}-2$. Thus, there is no need for any proof in this instance.

Comment: I meant $B=\mathbb{R}-\{2\}$, of course--my sloppiness, but I can't edit my comment above. :/

Answer (score 1):

As Ilham said, I think the formatting is a bit off. I believe you meant to say that $\alpha(x) = \frac{2x + 1}{x+2} $. If so assume $\alpha(a) = 2$ is true, then: 
$$ \frac{2a + 1}{a+2} = 2 $$

Which implies $ 2a+1 = 2a+ 4$ which is not true $\forall a \in \mathbb{R}$